# Firebase Cloud Function only triggerable by another function

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

In a Firebase Cloud Function I want to trigger other functions on command (these would be http functions, since I don't think there's another way to do this). I want to make these functions not callable by any user, but only from the admin sdk, from other cloud functions. How should I do that?

Comment: check out the PubSub: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/pubsub-events

Comment: thanks, exactly what I was looking for

Comment: Just to make sure, the topic I would create while doing this would only be accessible by the cloud function, so no one would be able to see any messages I send to it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTTP functions deployed by the Firebase CLI are made public by default.  You can choose not to make them public by configuring them to not allow [public access](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/authenticating/public) (requiring authentication).  This requires some knowledge about how the underlying Cloud Functions infrastructure works in Google Cloud Platform (Firebase does not expose all these details).  The documentation for securing functions starts [here](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/securing).

If you choose not to allow unauthenticated access, you will have to [provide IAM account credentials](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/securing/authenticating) in the request from the code that you do want to allow to invoke the function.